# Upper/Lower Bars using Dygraphs in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I would like to plot a chart like this one using Dygraphs library for R.

[Time Series charts with upper/lower bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWrH.png)

My data looks like the following data frame

```
> tail(DfDygraphPredictionObservedComps)

     Observed SLPrediction SLUpBand SLDwBand MLPrediction MLUpBand MLDwBand LLPrediction LLUpBand LLDwBand
2017-09-13   3.1351     3.120882 3.160430 3.109770     3.083619 3.180162 3.090038     3.085003 3.180162 3.090038
2017-09-14   3.1205     3.108331 3.145396 3.095604     3.077570 3.167217 3.073783     3.077475 3.167217 3.073783
2017-09-15   3.1104     3.113845 3.135238 3.085562     3.071449 3.157525 3.063275     3.073205 3.157525 3.063275
2017-09-18   3.1362     3.136071 3.160843 3.111557     3.081938 3.185797 3.086603     3.083608 3.185797 3.086603
2017-09-19   3.1360     3.134385 3.160354 3.111646     3.089192 3.186842 3.085158     3.091294 3.186842 3.085158
2017-09-20   3.1349     3.127217 3.158492 3.111308     3.090491 3.187005 3.082795     3.071906 3.187005 3.082795
```

I tried do the chart using the code below but the colors for each the upper/bands and series don't work

```
dygraph(DfDygraphPredictionObservedComps) %>% 
  dySeries(c("Observed"), label = "Observed") %>%
  dySeries(c("SLDwBand", "SLPrediction", "SLUpBand"), label = "SLPrediction") %>%
  dySeries(c("MLDwBand", "MLPrediction", "MLUpBand"), label = "MLPrediction") %>%
  dySeries(c("LLDwBand", "LLPrediction", "LLUpBand"), label = "MLPrediction") %>%
  dyRangeSelector()
```

Tks!! :)

Comment: After looking at the documentation for dygraphs, it looks as if something needs to be updated with the package?  The example they provide for handling multiple upper/lower bands in the same chart does not actually show upper or lower bands.  When I try to run their code, it does not display either.  You may want to submit an issue to their github repo.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use `library(quantmod)`,  `chart_Series` and `add_BBands()`